# gVIM has too much space between characters

Tags: fonts, gvim

I installed ubuntu 12.04 lts yesterday, and didn't change any system setting, but gvim can't get correct font display, there's too much space between character.

Screeshot :

[http://i.imgur.com/rm9hF.png](https://i.imgur.com/rm9hF.png)

The .gvimrc file:

[http://i.imgur.com/LngNy.png](https://i.imgur.com/LngNy.png)

Comment: What does `echo $LANG` say?

Comment: @jippie It says `zh_CN.UTF-8`

Comment: Hmm ... can't reproduce it that way, but it is worth to try the following `LANG=C gvim` or `LANG=en_US.UTF-8 gvim`. If that works, at least we know what to look for. Take a look at the Joar's answer too, I was able to reproduce his method.

Comment: I had a similar problem, it was because my guifont wasn't installed on the system.

Answer (score 6):

Try another font.

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_font:

> In gvim, you can change the font using the Edit menu, Select Font. An
>   alternative is to enter the command:
>
> ```
> :set guifont=*
> ```
>
> Once you have a font you like, you want to make it the default in the
>   future. Do
>
> ```
> :set guifont?
> ```
>
> and Vim will display something like
>
> ```
> guifont=Lucida_Console:h11
> ```
>
> Make a note of this string. Now put a line in your vimrc to set
>   guifont to this value, like this:
>
> ```
> if has('gui_running')
>   set guifont=Lucida_Console:h11
> endif
> ```
>
> Note: If there is a space in the text printed, such as
>
> ```
> guifont=Monospace 10
> ```
>
> it will be necessary to escape the space
>
> ```
> set guifont=Monospace\ 10
> ```

Comment: My font by default is `Monospace 10`, which looks normal. I'm curious why gvim on grick's system looks different.

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

- gvim 8.1.1401
- debian 10 (buster)
- X11 with ratpoison

worked to replace:

```
guifont=Monospace:h10
```

with

```
guifont=Monospace\ 10
```

similarily

```
set guifont=Source\ Code\ Pro\ for\ Powerline:h10
```

was replaced by

```
set guifont=Source\ Code\ Pro\ for\ Powerline\ 10
```

Not sure if it helps.